# Closing of Attribute Values in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Three developers, Bob, Bill, and Bruno, start creating a website and they begin to argue about which way of writing HTML markup (and CSS) is best.

**All Doctypes = `<!doctype html>`**

**Bob writes his markup like this:**

```
<style type=text/css media=screen>
    #container {
        background-image: url(http://goo.gl/qJKWj);
    }
</style>

<div id=container>
    <div id=header>...</div>
    <div id=content>...</div>
    <div id=footer>...</div>
</div>
```

**Bill writes his markup like this:**

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #container {
        background-image: url("http://goo.gl/qJKWj");
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

**Bruno writes his markup like this:**

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #container {
        background-image: url('http://goo.gl/qJKWj');
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id='header'>...</div>
    <div id='content'>...</div>
    <div id='footer'>...</div>
</div>
```

**As we can see:**

1. Bob does not like to enclose his
   attribute values with quotation
   marks of any kind.
2. Bill likes to use
   double quotation marks.
3. Bruno sometimes uses quotations and sometimes he doesn't.

They came to me for advice on which way of the above examples are the best for performance and which one is easier on the eyes. Is there a difference between them, other than cosmetic reasons?

What should I tell them?

Comment: Not sure which is worse: consistently writing invalid code (Bob) or writing valid but inconsistent code (Bruno).

Comment: Everyone seems convinced Bob's code is invalid, but it is not.

Comment: Bob's code *could be* wrong, depening on the doctype used. But above all, everyone agrees that Bruno's code sucks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added in the doctype that's being used.

Comment: Bill's code is the best. However, `type="text/css"` is superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-quotes are required by standards. They can be replaced with single quotes (optionally). No quotes is violation of the standard.

Update: quotes are strongly advised in HTML 4.0 (section 3.2.2), required in SGML (on which HTML was based) and XML and XHTML. CSS doesn't require quotes (i.e. they are optional) for URI values (as in your example, but still distinguishes between quoted and non-quoted values when it comes to keywords (see CSS 2, section 4.1.2)

Comment: Depends on the standard. If we are talking XHTML then yes. There are standards that do not force the XHTML standard on you... HTML5 for instance. You can use XTHML style if you wish but if you don't, thats cool too.

Comment: I thought so as well. But, @Glenn, That would explain why the Google Homepage doesn't use quotations seeing as it's in HTML5.

Comment: @Glenn HTML 4.0, section 3.2.2 strongly advises for quotes. CSS doesn't require quotes for URI values (I'll correct my answer).

Comment: @Shaz I updated my answer. As for Google -- it may let itself violate the standards in favor of smaller web page and faster loading time.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Even though it was a hypothetical situation, I always tend to use Bill's type of markup.  Though, since each character is a byte, all the quotations do add up. Even so, it makes "going with the flow" a lot easier by using them.

Answer (score 2):

As for whether the code is legal, it depends on the doctype that is set at the top of the HTML file. XHTML requires all attributes to be quoted and in lower case, whereas HTML5 isn't as strict, allowing for uppercase attributes and their values to be without quotes.

In terms of speed of processing/rendering, I can only guess but I'd say that attributes delimited by quotes would require less effort to separates and therefore be more efficient.

In terms of readability that's personal preference but I'd choose the double quotes every time.

But above all, consistency is key. Choose one and stick to it or it's just messy!

Comment: I think I agree most with your answer. Though, since both double and single quotations are allowed, some text editors highlight the syntax differently depending which one is used. For example, "foo" might be a brighter shade of green than 'bar'. If this is the case, would you still be advising that "we" use double quotations or would you let some leeway in terms of the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

As per XHTML/CSS W3C standards - Bills markup. See W3C for more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Conform to your spec. If you are
   using XHTML, you sure as schieße
   need to write XHTML
2. Have some standards across the
   project. If everyone does there own
   thing, code can be a pain to manage.

Essentially, go with what works best. If the issue is just a holy-war, who cares? If they all work on their own projects and get it done right, who cares?

If they all collaborate on the same code and this begins to be a problem, I would say pick on and run with it. As a side note, I prefer XHTML syntax.

Comment: @Shaz Are they work on a project together or are they independent? The answer to the situation is rather dependent on a plethora of variables.